# sc start intelhaxm with a error [SC] startservice failed 31: a device attached to the system is not functioning

Tags: android, intel

When I installed Intelhaxm through http://software.intel.com/en-us/android and I successfully installed, but when I try to verify the Intelhaxm in running or not in command prompt using administrator, I run the command "sc query intelhaxm" and it is showing state: 1 stopped and try to run " sc start intelhaxm" it is showing an error [SC] start service failed 31: a device attached to the system is not functioning..I didn't understand the problem.A solution, please.Appreciated.Thankyou

Comment: have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

One possible explanation is that your system is not supported by HAXM. Among other things, you need certain CPU extensions such as VT-x and NX. Note that AMD processors do not work as of the latest version (v7.2.0).

Also, to debug such issues: Download [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview), open it and make sure *Capture > Capture Kernel* is enabled. Filter by the string `hax` if your logs are polluted by too many events. After running `sc start intelhaxm` you should see what caused the driver initialization to fail.

Comment: **Error**:

' \Windows\System32>sc start intelhaxm
[SC] StartService FAILED 31:
device attached to the system is not functioning. ' 

_Log_: (DebugView kernel capture data ) 
**'Vt in not supported on the system , haxm installed sorry, 
haxm_error:haxm module init failed ,
 host initfailed '**